# GRUB2 insert additional modules

Tags: boot, grub2

GRUB2 doesn't have the `menu.lst` file.

How do I configure a boot script.

During boot, I hit <kbd>E</kbd> on the kernel image that I want to modify and make my modifications. But I would prefer to make the modifications in `/grub.d/` folder and then run `update-grub` command.

Basically, I am including certain modules at boot time, using `insmod`, there are too many such modules for me to do it every time, and Im unable to edit those different looking scripts GRUB has currently.

I figured that `/etc/grub.d/` contains files like

```
00_header
10_linux
...
```

but they look like scripts that I should be careful when I modify. Is there a easier way, like using `menu.lst` to configure `grub2`